# How to make static variable dynamic?

Tags: r, dynamic

Assume a simple code:

```
> sample(2,5,replace=TRUE)
[1] 2 1 1 1 2
```

When it is called again it can take other variables:

```
 > sample(2,5,replace=TRUE)
    [1] 1 2 2 1 2
```

However, when assigned to a variable it sticks to one predefined set:

```
> n <- (sample(2,5,replace=TRUE))
> n
[1] 1 1 2 1 1
> n
[1] 1 1 2 1 1
> n
[1] 1 1 2 1 1
```

How do we make n variable change its values then?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This is highly discouraged. Your code will become very hard to read and debug in the future for either you or people who will read the code. Just define a function so that you can call it again.

Comment: Stereo is right, and as others have mentioned further down, the idiomatic way to do it in R is to write a function for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm side-stepping some issues of why you'd want to do this, but here's one way that's somewhat....advanced:

```
makeActiveBinding("n",function() sample(2,5,replace = TRUE),.GlobalEnv)
> n
[1] 2 2 1 2 1
> n
[1] 1 2 2 2 2
> n
[1] 2 1 1 1 1
```

What's happening here is that `n` is being created in the global environment and then linked to the function, so that whenever a value for `n` is needed it calls the function.

Comment: nice solution but why oh why would some want to do this?!

Comment: @Stereo I agree, my default response would be to just write a function, like what DMC did. I just thought it would be fun to demonstrate something a bit more exotic.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a function would be the idiomatic R approach:

```
samp <- function() sample(2, 5, replace = TRUE)

samp()
[1] 2 1 2 2 2
samp()
[1] 1 2 2 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! - also great insight, but I was looking specifically for creating a non-functional variable that had the same properties as a function here

Answer (score 0):

... or simply call sample() several times...

```
> n <- sample(2,5, replace=TRUE)
> n
[1] 1 2 2 1 2
> n <- sample(2,5, replace=TRUE)
> n
[1] 2 2 2 1 1
```